# sails.js and foundation 6 - TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function

Tags: sails.js, zurb-foundation-6

I am trying to use sails.js and Zurb Foundation 6.2.  I used this handy [npm generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-generate-foundation) that sets up my grunt tasks.  The output looks pretty good.  I have a single js file that contains jquery, foundation, etc.

In my layout.ejs, I have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%=typeof title == 'undefined' ? 'New Sails App' : title%></title>

    <!-- Viewport mobile tag for sensible mobile support -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <!--STYLES-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/app.css">
    <!--STYLES END-->

  </head>


  <body>
...  some html ...
    <%- body %>

    <!--SCRIPTS-->
    <script src="/js/dependencies/sails.io.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/dependencies/foundation.js"></script>
    <!--SCRIPTS END-->
     <script>
            $(document).foundation();
        </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

When I run the page, I get this error:

```
**TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function
jQuery.fn.load()
 foundation.js:9612
<anonymous>
 foundation.js:11913
<anonymous>**
```

My reading on this suggests that the issue is either that something is not be loaded, is being loaded more than once, or is in the wrong order.  How do I narrow that down?  I tried to use CDN's for each piece and still couldn't make it work.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?  I got the same error when using 3.0.0, so I rolled back to 2.2.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Foundation is not currently compatible with jQuery 3.0.0, Foundation is using the deprecated `jQuery.fn.load()`.  Use jQuery 2.2.x for now.  See issue and PR:

https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/8834

https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/pull/8923

Comment: I found the issue a day after I posted this and forgot to update my initial post.  You are correct, it is the version of JQuery.